# Unity Implementation inside react-native

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project that in the future is supposed to implement certain elements of Augmented Reality. The thing is that for the AR part we were thinking of using Unity.
I've struggled to actually use unity's AR cuz my android phone doesn't support Google AR. Still, I'm still trying to learn how to actually implement a Unity app inside of another react-native app.
I've searched and I've searched and found that there are more questions than answers.
I've followed a lot of tutorials ant tips but to no avail.

But there was indeed one recurring library and tutorial that kept being mentioned: [@azesmway/react-native-unity](https://github.com/azesmway/react-native-unity). But as long as I'm concerned it works better on IOS than Android. Still, I found this article [PART I: Integrating Unity Games to React Native Apps. For Android.](https://medium.com/@salaheddine.ly/part-i-integrating-unity-games-to-react-native-apps-for-beginners-for-android-4c48031e2829) that also uses react-native-unity. So, I tried to follow the the instructions with a simple and new project but still I'm having some issues.

I tried debugging some things with ChatGPT but found myself running on circles by fixing and provoking the same errors. I'm a hundred percent sure that my issues lay on the Gradle configuration, but maybe I'm not knowledgeable enough to know how to actually set everything up correctly.

I'm currently modifying all the Gradle configuration files to fix these two errors that appear on the console after trying to open the app using an Android Studio Device Emulator.

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.      

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\...\AwesomeProject\unity\builds\android\unityLibrary\build.gradle' line: 6
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':unityLibrary'.
> Project with path 'mobilenotifications.androidlib' could not be found in project ':unityLibrary'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.        
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.    
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':unityLibrary'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.        
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.    
==============================================================================
```

I checked the files that are being mentioned on the error log but still I can't get rid of these two errors.

Regarding the fist error:

`android/build.gradle` looks like this

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.facebook.react.rootproject"
}
```

While `unity/builds/android/unityLibrary/build.gradle` looks somewhat like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project('mobilenotifications.androidlib')

}

android {
    ndkPath "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.20f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK"

    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.2'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }
...
```

I checked that the versions where the same and everything. Am I missing something?

Regarding the second error:
`android/settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'AwesomeProject'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')
include ':unityLibrary'
project(':unityLibrary').projectDir=new File('..\\unity\\builds\\android\\unityLibrary')

include ':mobilenotifications.androidlib'
project(':mobilenotifications.androidlib').projectDir = new File('..\\unity\\builds\\android\\mobilenotifications.androidlib')
```

I've tried with or without the last 3 lines, but still nothing. I've checked the existence of that directory and it is indeed there.

What can a do? Or is my problem residing somewhere else?

Comment: I tried using the react native unity wrapper...and it's a nightmare. We just went full unity in the end.